# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: disconnected: received Inspector.detached event with ChromeDriver and Selenium through Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, web-inspector

I'm getting an error

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_01Login (__main__.LoginTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/amal/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/Sucess/Test/Login_sj.py", line 29, in test_01Login
    driver.get("https://google.com")
  File "C:\Users\amal\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Users\amal\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\amal\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: disconnected: received Inspector.detached event
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.100)


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 8.615s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

while trying to automate a webpage using python 3.7 and selenium 3.141.0

This is in windows 10. My java version is jdk-12.0.2 and chrome driver is ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.68

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

I'm new to Automation and learning by trial and error and excuse for any mistake as I just created this account and trying to post in any forum for the first time. I tried to reinstall Java, Chrome and tried multiple versions of chromedriver. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: always put full error message in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: Yes sir, have been trying to resolve this issue for about 4-5 days and i see everyone recommends updating the chrome webdriver or java version. I see that it works in another machine without issues, not sure what else to compare. I'm adding full error in initial comment now as i'm unable to paste here.

Comment: sometimes chromedriver need specific version of chrome browser. Maybe with your error you should ask chromedriver's authors or chromdriver's forum.

Comment: error is in line 29. what else do you have in lines 1-28 ?

Comment: Actually all others have been commented out and only i'm calling the two lines above. My chrome driver is version 76.0.3809.68 and chrome browser is 76.0.3809.100. I have posted this query in chrome help forum also. Thanks @furas

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
WebDriverException: Message: disconnected: received Inspector.detached event
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was automatically disconnected when you tried to open the DevTools window.

As per the article [DevTools window keeps closing](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/help/devtools-window-keeps-closing) if you try to open the *DevTools* window when the *ChromeDriver* is busy executing *automated tests*, the *ChromeDriver* automatically gets disconnected and when *ChromeDriver* receives a command in disconnected state, it will attempt to close the *DevTools* window and reconnect back. Earlier Chrome's *DevTools* allowed only one debugger per page. But since ChromeDriver v2.x, it is now a *DevTools* debugging client.

If you need to inspect the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) through the DevTools, the best approach would be to pause your *test execution* so that ChromeDriver won't close the DevTools. When you complete inspecting [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) through Chrome, you can unpause your test and ChromeDriver will close the window and continue.

As per the discussion in [unknown error: cannot determine loading status from disconnected: received Inspector.detached](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1194) placing the *ChromeDriver* in path solves the issue. So you need to:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

PS: Ensure that you are using the latest *ChromeDriver v76.0* and *Chrome v76.0*.

Comment: I still see this issues on my Macbook. The solution you mentioned did not worked as well. 
The surprising part is that this issue happens randomly, I mean sometime works sometime get this error. And websites like duckduck go where I did not see this issue.


Error I'm getting
"""
>>Current google-chrome version is 91.0.4472
>>Get LATEST driver version for 91.0.4472
>>Driver 
.
.
 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: disconnected: received Inspector.detached event
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.77)

"""